# What's happening when I indent 'return' incorrectly

Tags: python

This is the code that returns the value I expect:

python

```
def function1():
    highest = 0
    for x in range(100):
        for y in range(100):
            if x+y > highest:
                highest = x+y
    return highest

print(function1())
```

This code prints "198".

Now, if I indent the return statement under the if statement, like this:

```
def function1():
    highest = 0
    for x in range(100):
        for y in range(100):
            if x+y > highest:
                highest = x+y
                return highest

print(function1())
```

The code prints "1".

Why? What's happening behind the scenes?

Sorry if this is a trivial question, but don't know the basic structure and stuff, I'm only learning by experimenting...

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python: what does the return statement do", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  You need to learn by more than mere experimentation; SO is not a tutorial service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is terminated in the second step of the second loop.

```
highest = 0
x = 0
y = 0

if 0+0 > 0 (false):
    increment y to 1:
```

the second run:

```
highest = 0
x = 0
y = 1
if 0+1 > 0 (true)
    highest = 1
    return # return command is called and therefore the execution of the function ends
```

A return statement ends the execution of the function call and "returns" the result.

Answer (score 0):

The return statement stops a loop at the point when you call it. So in the first example it goes through the whole for loop and then returns the value of `highest`. In the second example it returns on the first entry of the for loop, so it doesn't go through the whole for loop.

Answer (score 0):

A `return` statement ends the function. If you put it inside the `if` statement, the function stops as soon as the condition is true. So it will return the first value of `x+y` that's more than `0`, which happens when `x = 0` and `y = 1`, rather than continuing to look for higher values.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, the `return` statement is below both `for` loops, but is also indented outside of both of them. That means that it isn't reached until the nested `for` loop expression is evaluated for every possible combination of `x` and `y`.

On the other hand, in the second example, `return` is indented inside the `if` statement. Once the `if` statement is reached, the Python interpreter reads all lines indented at that level, including `return highest`. So the first time `x+y > highest` (which is when `x+y==1`, the if statement runs, and the function returns `1`. The return acts as an early break, so even though there will be more values that it *could* process, it doesn't matter because you explicitly told it to return early.